# pread and pwrite not defined?

Tags: c, linux, atomic, glibc, unistd.h

I am trying to use pread and pwrite so that I can lseek to the beginning of the file and start reading or writing in one atomic operation.  Both of these functions will do that for me however, the issue I am having is that the compiler is giving me `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘pread’` even after I added `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500` and `#include<unistd.h>` like the man pages said.  Am I missing something? The two statements with the function calls are below.
Thanks!

```
 #include<unistd.h>



 #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {



while ( (read_in += pread(source_fd, in_buf, in_buf_size,read_in) )  )
    {

if (write_out += pwrite(dest_fd, in_buf, read_in, write_out) == -1)
        {
```

Comment: Can you show the entire code?

Comment: @Mysticial sure, I added all of the code as an edit.  I thought that it might be too much code to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define `_XOPEN_SOURCE 500` ***before*** your includes:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

#include<unistd.h>
```

Otherwise, the `unistd.h` header won't see the macro definition.

Comment: Thank you! Perhaps it would be useful for me to know what the _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 is for so that I will better understand it, would you happen to know what that is?

Comment: @tpar44 *If  defined  (with  any  value),  expose  POSIX.1,  POSIX.2,  and  X/Open (XPG4) definitions. If defined **with the value 500 or greater**, also expose SUSv2 (UNIX 98 and XPG5) extensions.*